# Duplicate data displaying on crystal reports

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

I have a code like this to display data on datagridview (To check) and crystal reports

```
private void PrintReportForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      // Getting result from SQL server database using LINQ to SQL
      var result = AccessorReports.GetVoucherDetailByVoucherNo(VoucherNo);

      // Displaying result on data grid view
       dataGridView1.DataSource = result;

       // Displaying result on crystal report
       VoucherRpt cr = new VoucherRpt();
       cr.Load("VoucherRpt.rpt");
       cr.SetDataSource(result);
       crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cr;
}
```

The problem is I am getting duplicate entry on crystal report while data grid view showing single entry. Why?  (Screenshot attached)[image: For each entry in data grid view there is duplicate entry on crystal report]

For each entry in data grid view there is duplicate entry on crystal report.
Thanks for help in advance :)

Screenshot of how tables are linked

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check the link in your crystal report document. If there is table that is not linked with other properly then it can show duplicate records like this. for example if you have another table which has 3 records then every record will be displayed 3 times. if there is any table that is not being used in the report then remove it from Database Explorer.

You are using Disconnected DataSource method to display report.

```
cr.SetDataSource(result);
```

This method will show data only which you have specified in datasource. Report will not check the data in sql server. so, make sure you have assign all the table data which are selected in Database Explorer. for example if you have taken 3 tables in your report then your dataset should contain 3 tables.

```
//ds.Tables[0] : "table1"
//ds.Tables[1] : "table2"
//ds.Tables[2] : "table3"

cr.SetDataSource(ds);
```

Comment: Hi, i have attached the screenshot of how the two tables are linked. I think they are linked properly. (screenshot on original post). thnx

Comment: in your C# code you are assigning `result` object into `SetDataSource()` method. does it having both table data `Voucher_Details` and `Voucher`? One more thing that if the `V_NO` is primary key field than it should not displayed `blank` in the report. Do you have enabled `SuppressIfDuplicate` option for that field? if not then it should show value. You should also try to `show` report without assigning datasource. I mean remove the `SetDataSource` method and try again.